# font-face+chrome+django: how to avoid message "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream."

Tags: django, google-chrome, font-face

My font-face rules are:

```
font-face{
   font-family: 'name';
   src: url(path) format("truetype");
}
```

but dom inspector (in Chrome+django) throws this warning:
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream.

So how to avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

I am just wondering why you "must" use font-face. Perhaps using [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) instead would resolve this?

Comment: I'm creating a text editor, so i need several font types. I may use a service like Google WebFont or other service, have you got some advice to choose among several services, specially in terms of performance?

Cufon seems to me a strange solution, why may i use it instead of a standard font-face solution?

Comment: The question is "HOW does" not "WHY should" one use django + FONT-FACE + chrome together.